# Failure Attempting to Update to Gradle 8.0.2

Tags: gradle, cmake

I have an Android project that's currently on Gradle 7.4.2, but when I try to update to Gradle 8, I get this error

Could not find method cmake() for arguments [build_btmgqcp14ick6velpsxwzt8gv$_run_closure2$_closure10$_closure15$_closure20@45895218]
on BuildType$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=externalNativeBuild, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}
of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType$AgpDecorated.

All of our modules are Kotlin. We use Firebase for analytics and crash monitoring.

Firebase pulls in the need for NDK and Cmake.

The project Gradle file has this

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    ext.espresso_version = '3.5.1'
    ext.hamcrest_version = '2.2'
    ext.androidx_test_version = '1.4.0'
    ext.androidx_test_rules_version = '1.5.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
//        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The module Gradle is too big to share the whole thing. Here are the CMake parts

```
    defaultConfig {
...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
```